# Probability in table reservations

Tags: probability

In general, after a group makes a reservation at a restaurant, they do not show up 20% of the time.

If a restaurant has 8 reservations for the evening, what is the probability that exactly two do not show up?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: use the binomial thoerem